# Python not appearing as option for parser in label expression dialog of ArcGIS Desktop 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap, labeling, python-parser

I have ArcMap 10.0 and python is not appearing as a parser option in the label expression dialog box, only VBScript and JScript. Python is installed and the python window works fine.

Any idea how I can get this function?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 was moved to Retired status last month. There's a lot of "current" functionality not available at 10.0

Answer (score 3):

[The Python Parser for Label Expressions only became available at ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/What_s_new_for_text/016w00000054000000/):

> **New Label Expression parser**
>
> At ArcGIS 10.1 there has been a new label expression parser added. You
>   can now use Python to add logic to your label expressions, including
>   conditional logic and looping. For example, you could produce labels
>   that have only the first letter of each word capitalized, regardless
>   of how the text strings are stored in the attribute fields.

Consequently, to get access to this function you will need to upgrade to ArcGIS 10.1 (or later) for Desktop.

Comment: Well that explains that. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: if this answers your question, please accept it as the answer.  See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)